# Convert Publisher<CompletedFileUpload> to Maybe<HttpResponse<?>>

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2, reactivex, rx-java3

I have the below method

```
public Maybe<HttpResponse<?>> post(Publisher<CompletedFileUpload> files) {
        MultipartBody.Builder requestBody = MultipartBody.builder();
        return Flowable.fromPublisher(files).flatMap(file -> {
            requestBody
                    .addPart("file", file.getFilename(), MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE, file.getBytes())
                    .addPart("id", "asdasdsds");
            return this.iProductClient.post(requestBody.build());
        });
    }
```

The return type from `this.iProductClient.post(requestBody.build());` is `Maybe<HttpResponse<?>>`

How can I convert the below code to return `Maybe<HttpResponse<?>>`, currently the below method has error

```
return Flowable.fromPublisher(files).flatMap(file -> {
            requestBody
                    .addPart("file", file.getFilename(), MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE, file.getBytes())
                    .addPart("id", "asdasdsds");
            return this.iProductClient.post(requestBody.build());
        });
```

Comment: You have presumably multiple files and thus multiple `Maybe`s. How should they be turned into one `Maybe` from a logic stance?

Comment: @akarnokd basically what I want is to loop all the files and add to the MultipartBody, and call this.iProductClient.post(requestBody.build()). However the return type of post method is Maybe<HttpResponse<?>>. Thus I need to return Maybe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `collect` and then flatmap in the requrest sending:

```java
return Flowable.fromPublisher(files)
    .collect(MultipartBody::builder, (requestBody, file) -> {
        requestBody
            .addPart("file", file.getFilename(), MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE, file.getBytes())
            .addPart("id", "asdasdsds");
    })
    .flatMapMaybe(requestBody -> iProductClient.post(requestBody.build()))
    ;
```

Comment: Is there any way on flatMapMaybe(requestBody -> iProductClient.post(requestBody.build())) to check if addPart has been added or not to the requestBody ?

Comment: What properties does `MultipartBody` have?

Comment: Didn't find such properties to check. It has build, addpart  methods

Comment: https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-multipart-body/size/

Comment: well I tried flatMapMaybe(requestBody -> { if(requestBody.size)}), but size is not present

Comment: In Java, it is a method: `size()`.